# Django + google app engine + spreadsheets api

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-docs, google-docs-api

I would like to know if **Google Docs API** or **any other spreadsheet (xls) API** or **any reporting tool** works with **GAE, Django & application data from BigTable**. In other words, I would like to generate spreadsheet with rich formatting - colors, fonts and upto 50 sheets in each file. And send this spreadsheet as E-Mail attachment to user or download using browser.

Thanks a lot,
Sandeep

Answer (score 3):

I've used [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) to good effect with Django + AppEngine. Openpyxl can do styles and sheets and formatting and all that stuff, and saves to an `.xlsx` file. If you need `.xls` files, then perhaps have a look at something like [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

If your spreadsheets are under 1MB, then they can be saved in/served with the Datastore just fine. Otherwise, you can use the Blobstore, but that would require using the AppEngine API instead of pure Django.